# Run command line arguments in python script

Tags: python, shell

I have a program that is run from the command line like this

```
python program.py 100 rfile
```

How can I write a *new* script so that instead of running it with just the '100' argument, I can run it consecutively with a list of arguments like [50, 100, 150, 200]?

Edit: The reason I am asking is that I want to record how 'program.py' executes with different arguments.

Comment: Do you want multiple arguments or a single argument that is a python list?

Comment: Added the [shell] and [shell-scripting] tags; not sure if this is what the OP has in mind, but it seems like the most obvious approach to at least a couple of people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create a bash file like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  python program.py $i rfile
done
```

then do `chmod +x` on that file, when you run it, it will run these consecutively:

```
python program.py 1 rfile
python program.py 2 rfile
python program.py 3 rfile
python program.py 4 rfile
python program.py 5 rfile
```

Comment: If you change `1 2 3 4 5` to `$@`, you can pass the list of numbers when you run the script, e.g. `the_new_bash_script 1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: actually, change it to `"$@"` so you can do `the_new_script 1 2 "3 4" 5`

Answer (score 6):

You can use Devrim's shell approach or you can modify your script:

If your original script worked like this:

```
import sys
do_something(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

You could accomplish what you want like this:

```
def main(args):
    for arg in args[:-1]:
        do_something(arg, args[-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

You would invoke it like so:

```
python program.py 50 100 150 200 rfile
```

I'm guessing at what you want. Please clarify if this isn't right.

Comment: I may not have explained what I wanted to do very well. I do not want to modify the 'program.py' file I originally mentioned. I want to create a new script that runs the 'program.py' script multiple times on a list of arguments, using one argument each time.

Comment: @Chris, it might be easiest to use Devrim's shell approach. It's easy to call functions in other python files, but not quite as easy if program.py doesn't have something like a "main function". Do you know what I mean? (Are you familiar with Python?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

It lets you use your program like : `python yourcode.py --input input.txt --output output.txt`

This is great when you have a number of console arguments.

So in your case you could do something like:

```
parser.add_option("-i","--input", action="store", type="int", nargs=4, dest="mylist")
```

Now in your console you can type in `python program.py -i 50 100 150 200`

In order to access the inputs you can use mylist as a list.

Comment: Note: As of Python 2.7 Optparse has been deprecated and replaced by the nearly identical argparse.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in your python script, you can arrange for it to take a list of integers by using the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module (*untested code*):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('rfile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('numbers', nargs='+', type=int)
ns = parser.parse_args()
```

Such activities are usually conducted under the auspices of a `main` function as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939196/run-command-line-arguments-in-python-script/3939206#3939206) by Jon-Eric.

If you call the resulting script from the shell with

```
python the_script.py filename 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

you will end up with `ns.file` being equal to the file `filename`, opened for read access, and `ns.numbers` being equal to the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

`argparse` is totally awesome and even prints out usage information for the script and its options if you call it with `--help`.  You can customize it in far too many ways to explain here, just read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html).

`argparse` is in the standard library as of Python 2.7; for earlier pythons it can be installed as a module in the normal way, e.g. via `easy_install argparse`, or by virtue of being a dependency of the package that your script is part of.